# How IP layer check if it is DHCP request

Tags: networking

When a DHCP request packet is received on router(configured with ip-helper), it redirects it to DHCP server. I would like to know that how router come to know that it is DHCP request packet. As it is defined by port no. which exist on transport layer. in Same way, how a router uses TCP port for BGP. But how could router use transport layer port no. as it is L3 device.

Comment: DHCP requests are broadcasts

Comment: I know that it is a broadcast, However i would like to know that how a router learn that is is is for DHCP request. Or, if host is searching for DNS entry then how a router learn it, As both requests are defined  on transport layer port no.

Comment: Broadcast to port 67 from client with port 68

Comment: host can not search for anything because it does not have an IP address to query any DNS.

Comment: Router is a layer 3 device. It means that it would read IP packet. But DHCP port defined on TCP layer. So how would router come to know that it is a DHCP or DNS request.

Comment: my friend, remove from your head DHCP or DNS, think as a machine... If you have a DHCP Server on the network it will listen to all packages sent to port 67 (DHCP). Now the Router see that someone is sending a boradcast with the port 67, it have configure .." hey let's foward everything that we got from port 67 to this IP" meaning this IP is the DHCP server in another interface etc. Remember the port respond to a service in this case port 67 is DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

As [Vidal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11081046/vidal) said, DHCP requests are broadcast.

1. A host(the DHCP client), upon joining the networking will send out a DHCP discovery broadcast message. It doesn't know the address of the DHCP server, so it will talk with everyone currently connected to the network to discover if a DHCP server exists. The port is 67.
2. If there is a DHCP server, it will offer an IP address to the host. There might be many DHCP servers, in this case, it'll take the IP address of the first DHCP server that responded.
3. Once the host selects an IP address, it will send a DHCP request back to the server for that specific IP address.
4. The DHCP server will then acknowledge this message and confirm the DHCP lease to the client.

For a more clearer explanation, just read this [article.](https://afteracademy.com/blog/what-is-dhcp-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Router is a layer 3 device. It means that it would read IP packet. But DHCP port defined on TCP layer. So how would router come to know that it is a DHCP or DNS request.